# filter construction that no longer works

Tags: ms-access, vba

this filter statement work in other access software until I began constructing a new continuous form and now no longer works

```
 Me.Filter = "[ItemNomen] like '*'" & "And [VendorNbr] = " & Vendor_Nbr
 Me.FilterOn = True
```

I haven't had an issue with the statement until just recently.  it seems the issue is with the "like " statement.  I'm self-taught and therefore at a total loss on why it no longer works.  any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a space before the `And`, corrected here:

```
Me.Filter = "[ItemNomen] like '*'" & " And [VendorNbr] = " & Vendor_Nbr
```

A more logical approach would be to just remove the string concatenation:

```
Me.Filter = "[ItemNomen] like '*' And [VendorNbr] = " & Vendor_Nbr
```

And, knowing that `[ItemNomen] Like '*'` matches anything except null values, you're better off using `IS NOT NULL`:

```
Me.Filter = "[ItemNomen] IS NOT NULL And [VendorNbr] = " & Vendor_Nbr
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I still ran into difficulties so I started to construct a query using "like" in the criteria entry.  "Like" was changed to "ALike" and the query failed.  research on "ALike" revealed that having the database in "Sql Server Compaible Syntax (ANSI 92) mode selected caused "Like" to be changed to "ALike" and the wildcard is now "%", not the asterisk.  I deselected the option and incorporated your last suggestion and was met with success.  Thanks for your comments.  You have been a big help.